# Cordova CLI overwriting Plugman plugin on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

I'm writing a Plugman-compatible Cordova plugin. Installing it via Plugman, I've confirmed it installs correctly and runs normally:

```
plugman --platform android --project /platforms/android --plugin my/plugin.path
```

But if I use:

```
cordova build/cordova run android
```

it doesn't work even with plugin installed. This is because Plugman only installs my plugin js file to the /platforms/android/assets/www folder and not the base /www folder, so when I build, the /www folder without the plugin gets copied to /platforms/android/assets/www.

Is there an option or something in plugin.xml I should be specifying to install the plugin to the project root www folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Cordova CLI, you shouldn't install plugins using plugman.  Cordova CLI does use plugman under the covers, but what you want to use is `cordova plugins add http://...` or `cordova plugins add /path/to/plugin.xml`.

You didn't specify which version of Cordova you are using, but here's some examples of adding plugins that are core functionality: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Comment: Using cordova plugins add, the rest of my plugin gets added (AndroidManifest.xml additions, libs) but the js file doesn't get copied to the assets/www folder like it does when I use plugman?

Comment: Right.  I'm not sure what your plugin.xml file looks like but if you are using js-module (and not asset) for your js files, cordova takes care of injecting the js itself, and stores it off in a different directory.  See here for more: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification

Answer (score 0):

It should put the js files in platforms/android/assets/www/plugins/com.plugin-name/www and the java files in platforms/android/src/com/plugin-name/

You can specify this in the plugin.xml file like this (this is an example from a plugin that I upgraded to https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin3.0 ()):

```
<js-module src="www/sms.js" name="Sms">
    <clobbers target="window.sms" />
</js-module>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Sms">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.adamwadeharris.sms.Sms"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/Sms.java" target-dir="src/com/adamwadeharris/sms" />
</platform>
```